# How to fetch only odd entries from a file using awk command in a pipe delimited file?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Need to fetch only odd columns from a file which is pipe delimited.

```
SOURCE_FILE
1|ABC|WORK|1234
2|DEF|OFFICE|5678
3|GHI|HOME|9012
4|JKL|PERSONAL|3456
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
1|WORK
2|OFFICE
3|HOME
4|PERSONAL
```

I try using `awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) $i="" } 1' OFS="|" New2.txt >> delimt.txt`, but it removes the values and not the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){val=(val?val OFS:"") $i};print val;val=""}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Without using variable and should be fast than 1st solution try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){printf("%s%s",$i,(i==NF ||i==(NF-1)) && i%2!=0?ORS:OFS)}}' Input_file
```

OR(adding a non-one liner form of above solution):

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
    printf("%s%s",$i,(i==NF || i==(NF-1)) && i%2!=0?ORS:OFS)
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1|WORK
2|OFFICE
3|HOME
4|PERSONAL
```

Comment: Thanks Ravinder Singh. It works perfectly as expected.

Comment: @PraveenP, your welcome, happy tp help, keep learning and keep sharing on this great site SO.

Comment: Why not use NF>1 as well?

Comment: @ClaesWikner, sorry I didn't get it where exactly you are asking for this condition to be placed?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. Since in OP example header is removed you could put in front of  your "{for", just my two cents.

Comment: @PraveenP, Request you to please do mention the reason of deselecting correct answer, could try to improve it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Deselection happened unknowingly, sorry for it. Used your code and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
 awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" ' { for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) { printf("%s%s",s,$i);s="|"; } print "";s=""  } '
```

with given inputs

```
$ cat praveen.txt
1|ABC|WORK|1234
2|DEF|OFFICE|5678
3|GHI|HOME|9012
4|JKL|PERSONAL|3456

$ awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" ' { for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) { printf("%s%s",s,$i);s="|"; } print "";s=""  } ' praveen.txt
1|WORK
2|OFFICE
3|HOME
4|PERSONAL

$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Easily understandable. Learnt a way to do it better.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with coreutils as well:

```
cols=$(head -n1 infile | tr '|' '\n' | wc -l)
cut -d'|' -f$(seq -s, 1 2 $cols) infile
```

Output:

```
1|WORK
2|OFFICE
3|HOME
4|PERSONAL
```

Comment: Really a good suggestion. I gave only a sample entries in question, but actual file had n number of entries. So providing numbers doesn't seems a good idea in my case.